# Vagrant + Chef error

Tags: ruby, vagrant

Tengo un instancia centos montada con vagrant pero estoy teniendo problemas para poder provisionar git y composer.

A ver si podeis echarme un cable.

```
    config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "chef-sugar"    
    chef.add_recipe "seven_zip"     
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "openssl"
    chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
    chef.add_recipe "composer"
    chef.add_recipe "git"
end
```

Yo descargue todas las cookbook de supermarket.

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> ==> default: Running handlers:
>
> ==> default: [2016-04-14T14:21:56+01:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
>
> ==> default: Running handlers complete
>
> ==> default: [2016-04-14T14:21:56+01:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
>
> ==> default: Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
>
> ==> default: [2016-04-14T14:21:56+01:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
>
> ==> default: [2016-04-14T14:21:56+01:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
>
> ==> default: [2016-04-14T14:21:56+01:00] ERROR: Cookbook windows not found. If you're loading windows from another cookbook, make sure you
>   configure the dependency in your metadata
>
> ==> default: [2016-04-14T14:21:56+01:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited
>   unsuccessfully (exit code 1) Chef never successfully completed! Any
>   errors should be visible in the output above. Please fix your recipes
>   so that they properly complete.

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes es que *Chef* no esta encontrando los *cookbooks* en tu sistema, la propiedad **chef.cookbooks_path** por defecto tiene el directorio *cookbooks* como valor, relativo a la ubicacion del *vagrantfile*, por tanto deberia ser algo asi:

-Vagranfile
|- /cookbooks

Verifica que tu estructura se ajusta a esto.

Documentacion Vangrant: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_solo.html#cookbooks_path

Comment: Si me olvidaba, esto solo aplica para *Chef* en modo local.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Ipman1971. No es ese mi problema porque copié la carpeta cookbooks en mi directorio de vagrantFile Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Solo por probar, no vaya a ser que concatene con el valor por defecto *chef.cookbooks_path* prueba a eliminar la propiedad de la configuración o a crear un directorio cookbooks dentro de cookbooks, vamos a ver que pasa

Comment: Probé pero efectivamente, me salta error de que no encuentra mis cookbooks